# View like Comments in facebook

Tags: iphone, ios

I am building an app in which I got stuck at a position where I need to do something like commenting on photo in Facebook.

[image]

There should be image at top and we can be able to add comment in lower portion. Now, my question is how can this be achieved - I think I have two option- 1.Go with custom UIView and go on increasing Uiview. 2. Go with table view.

Any idea, how we can be able to achieve this thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Definitely a `UITableView`** with a custom `UITableViewCell` with a `UIImageView` for the picture and a few `UILabels` for each different text (name, comment, time etc). Then you need to be able to calculate the height of each individual row in

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

---

The bottom most part where the user enters their new comment should be a separate view with a `UIButton` and a `UITextField`

Comment: Thanx david, I was also thinking for the same..Custom UITableViewCell will definitely work for me..let me give a try

Comment: @iCoder4777 I want to create same comment view as in Facebook app https://imgur.com/a/AfXD2RA. The view hierarchy as  I understand is: UViewController, on top of it has a UITableView and on the bottom of it there is a custom UIView with a textField and a Send UIButton. Facebook UIViewController seems to be richer, in the sense that one can send video and images as well. I will not be able to display such content in a UITextField. It looks like they have custom UIViewController. Is there an out of the box library I can easily implement to achieve same result? Please advise how can I do it?